# asp.net core 3 rotativa startup.cs env problem

Tags: asp.net-core-3.0, rotativa, asp.net-core-3.1

Im try to use Rotativa ım follow this [guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=68YcKP0g1XA)
in start.cs in configure function ım add this code

```
  RotativaConfiguration.Setup(env);
```

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment'
```

ım search this error and find this and convert my code like this

```
 RotativaConfiguration.Setup(env.WebRootPath, "Rotativa");
```

and its give me this error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment'
```

ım add Rotative folder in wwwroot and added 
wkhtmltoimage.exe, wkhtmltopdf.exe

my package version Rotativa.aspnetcore v1.1.1
ım using current asp.net core version 3.xx
 what is problem any one can be explain me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im find a solution like this in statup.cs in configure function  add env2 and obsolute

```
        [Obsolete]
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment env2)
```

and change this like

```
   RotativaConfiguration.Setup(env2);
```

its working now but ıts bad solution if you know better one pls describe it.

### Works on versions 3.0 and 3.1

```
// Rotary configuration 
// This is for the rotating to use the files in the Rotating folder
RotativaConfiguration.Setup (env.ContentRootPath, "Rotativa");
```

Comment: If it's not an answer and/or is obsolete, why not remove yours?

Answer (score 17):

Remove existing Rotativa.AspNetCore from Nuget packages then install the beta version:

`Install-Package Rotativa.AspNetCore -Version 1.2.0-beta`

This has the overload method in it that also works with **IWebHostingEnvironment**

After installing configure in Configure method as:

```
RotativaConfiguration.Setup(env.WebRootPath, "Rotativa");
```

Answer (score 0):

install
`Install-Package Rotativa.AspNetCore -Version 1.2.0-beta`

set Rotativa environment variable to
`RotativaConfiguration.Setup(env.WebRootPath, "/usr/bin/");`

If you are on Ubuntu 20.10 or 20.04 install wkhtmlpdf.
`sudo apt install wkhtmlpdf`

This works for Dot Net Core 3.1 or 5.0 I have tested both.